# How to find the right cluster algorithm?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I would like to find the algorithm which circumvent  some drawbacks of k-Means:

Given:

```
x<- c(4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8)
y<- c(2,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,6,8,4,5,6,5,7,8,9,9,9,10)

matrix<-cbind(x,y)# defining matrix
Kmeans<-kmeans(matrix,centers=2) # with 3 centroids

plot(x,y,col=Kmeans$cluster,pch=19,cex=2)
points(Kmeans$centers,col=1:3,pch=3,cex=3,lwd=3)
```

Here I would like have an algorithm clustering the data into two clusters divided by a diagonal from left corner to right corner.

Comment: This wouldn't minimize the within-group inerty, will it? Thus I think you're looking for something that is not clustering. Have you thought about fitting two lines? Or try fitting a gaussian mixture? The true question is: why do you think your groups should be like this?

Comment: hmm, its seems like a natural choice. I mean obviously there is some linearity. However I thought to find a cluster algorithm which might approximate my feeling towards the two clusters.

Comment: I think a mixture of Gaussians might work well in this case. The algorithm will automately choose how many clusters you need (here 2) and their correlation structure (here 45°-stretched). I don't know yet the package you'd need, but it shouldn't be too hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for can be solved in multiple ways. Here are two:

1. First way is to simply define the separating line of you clusters. Since you know how your points should be grouped (by a line) you can use that.

If you want your line to start at the origin, then simply check if x > y:

```
x<- c(4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8)
y<- c(2,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,6,8,4,5,6,5,7,8,9,9,9,10)

thePoints <- cbind(x,y)


as.integer(thePoints[,1] > thePoints[,2])
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This will put points above the diagonal (starting at 0) in one group, and others - to another group. Keep in mind that if your line may not go through the origin (0) then you have to modify this example a bit.

2. Kmeans with correlation distance:

The K-means function:

```
myKmeans <- function(x, centers, distFun, nItter=10) {
    clusterHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
    centerHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")

    for(i in 1:nItter) {
        distsToCenters <- distFun(x, centers)
        clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
        centers <- apply(x, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
        # Saving history
        clusterHistory[[i]] <- clusters
        centerHistory[[i]] <- centers
    }

    list(clusters=clusterHistory, centers=centerHistory)
}
```

And correlation distance:

```
myCor <- function(points1, points2) {
    return(1 - ((cor(t(points1), t(points2))+1)/2))
}

theResult <- myKmeans(mat, centers, myCor, 10)
```

As was also displayed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082378/how-to-compute-distances-between-centroids-and-data-matrix-for-kmeans-algorithm/27088515#27088515)

Here how both solution would look like:

```
plot(points, col=as.integer(points[,1] > points[,2])+1, main="Using a line", xlab="x", ylab="y")
plot(points, col=theResult$clusters[[10]], main="K-means with correlation clustering", xlab="x", ylab="y")
points(theResult$centers[[10]], col=1:2, cex=3, pch=19)
```

[image: linevskmeans]

So it's more about what kind of distance measure you are using and not about some kind of deficiency of K-means.

You can also find better implementations of K-means with correlation distance for R instead of using the one I provided here.

Comment: Beware that k-means may fail to converge if you use other distance functions. In particular for absolute correlation distance, I can give a counterexample why the *mean* is inappropriate to use. In this particular data set, I'm not convinced that there are really two clusters, either. Given the values are integer and the data set is small, it may just be chance. Engineering the clustering to fit your assumptions is a form of **overfitting**!

Comment: Thank you for an insightful comment @Anony-Mousse. Regarding the use of `1-((cor+1)/2)` distance: it's not really an absolute correlation, but rather correlation transformed to a distance between 0 and 1. It should be proportional to euclidean distance of scaled points. I don't really see why it should fail to converge, but if you have a counter example - that would solve it.

Comment: And regarding overfitting - you are correct if we assume that the data has some "cluster structure" and there is "true" number of clusters that needs to be discovered. However clustering also can be arbitrary. And we can find several real-world examples where this kind of clustering (by diagonal) is meaningful. i.e. -  objects are peoples heads. x=amount of grey hair, y=amount of non-grey hair. Then it does make sense to cluster people based on x>y. Because that is prior knowledge about the problem we have. It is above over-fitting. No fitting was needed to come up with the groups and method.

Comment: Correlation (in particular global ones) do not mean it is meaningful to forcibly cluster this way. It means we should reduce and decorelate features... because otherwise, you have double weight on the correlated features; in other words a difference in grey-haired means also a difference in non-gray-haired, and you shouldn't count this twice.

Comment: In above example, simply clustering `x-y` may already do the trick, and if using the difference is supported by theory that should be fine.

Comment: But I don't count the distances twice - the measurement is of amount of hair, not ratio or percentage. And the total amount of hair can vary from person to person. And it's not "forcibly clustering" anything.. There is no clustering method that is free of assumptions. I (or in this case OP) simply stated his assumption - data should be separated by angle. And correlation does that. And you are pushing another assumption - that data should be clustered by "closeness" ? Isn't that simply another kind of assumption? It is only meaningful when the assumptions are correct. In this case - not.

Comment: The correlation of 2d values is pretty much useless, too. Not only is it inconsistent with the mean (which can ruin k-means badly), it isn't really well-defined for 2d data, but you need a reasonable sample size (here: dimensionality) for the numbers to make sense.

Comment: I am not sure how to respond.. First you claimed that it will not converge, I think it will, but I was not sure. Yet we don't have the counter example. Then you said that assumptions is a form of overfitting, when in fact the opposite is true - stronger assumptions (regularization) is the main method to combat overfitting. Then you said I counted something twice, which I didn't. Sorry if this sounded rude, but it's not. I am just trying to understand where are you coming from and what you are trying to say exactly. Maybe I am wrong somewhere. But so far I don't see it.

Comment: In 2d, correlation will always be +1 or -1 - or UNDEFINED... try adding point (2,2) to your data set and see what happens.

Comment: OK I admit I don't see yet how correlation is inconsistent with the mean. But I am willing to learn - can you give some simple example maybe?

Comment: (1,2,3,4,5) and (-1,-2,-3,-4,-5) have an absolute correlation of 1. But their mean is (0,0,0,0,0), and the correlation with the mean is undefined. **The mean does not minimize correlations with it.** The mean is a least-squares optinizer, it is appropriate for squared Euclidean distance.

Comment: In the 2D example here, your distance function is not defined for any point on the diagonal (where x=y)... in other words, you have a line of undefined values separating your data set into two... Anything above will be similar to each other, and so will anything below. But it boils down to testing whether x,y is positively or negatively correlated.

Comment: Yes I have to agree - there are undefined values. That may also stop the algorithm from converging if the mean gets on diagonal. Hmm. But the problem here is the same like one we would have trying to scale our samples (by subtracting mean and dividing by sd). However if the samples are all "scalable" than no centroid should be able to get on the diagonal. The example with (1,2,3,4,5) and (-1,-2,-3,-4,-5) does not apply, because absolute correlation is NOT what I was using. And checking correlation of x,y - what would that do? I can have a cloud of points and still want to cluster like that.

Comment: Have some time to continue this in chat for a bit?

Comment: The example was for absolute correlation, but I guess a similar example can be designed for your correlation, too. Unless you can prove that the **mean** of a set of vectors never yields an increased correlation with it. The proof for squared deviation is standard literature; so k-means does converge with L2 cluster assignments _and_ L2 mean recomputation. k-medians does the same for L1 - the median is the least-absolute-deviation estimator of centrality. But what _is_ the minimum-correlation estimator?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Mclust` from the `mclust` package, it will try to fit a Gaussian mixture on your data.
The default behavior:

```
mc = Mclust(matrix);
points(t(mc$parameters$mean));
plot(mc);
```

.. will find 4 groups, but you might be able to force it to 2 or to force the correlation structure for the Gaussians to be stretched in the right direction.

Be aware that it'll be hard to interpret and justify the meaning of your groups unless you understand very well the reason why you *want* them to be 2 etc..